# What is the difference between PySpark's featuresCol, labelCol, predictionCol, and probabilityCol?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, apache-spark, pyspark

I am attempting to train a random forest classifier (`pyspark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier`) on a large dataset (~70gb). However, I am not sure what to send to each of featuresCol, labelCol, predictionCol, and probabilityCol.

From the docs I gather that:

1. `featuresCol` is a list of features from your dataframe
2. `labelCol` is the target feature
3. `predictionCol` is also the target feature, but generated by the model (not sure). Do I need to set this prior to training?
4. `probabilityCol` is the probability of each class as a vector. Is this similar to sklearn's `class_weight`? ie does the model account for a low diversity? If so how?

Additionally, can I set an option for OOB_score?

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(featuresCol=feature_cols, labelCol=target_col, numTrees=300, MaxDepth=15, Impurity='gini', maxMemoryInMB=2**10)
clf_t = clf.fit(train)

y_train_pred = clf_t.transform(test)
y_test_pred = clf_t.transform(test)
```

Here's a link to the docs: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#module-pyspark.ml.classification